# Connecting Python Backend to Android APP

Tags: python, xamarin

How to use python as a backend for an Android App that is built using C#?  The Python Backend is written using the Flask framework. The Android app is built using xamarin.

Comment: Look into Iron Python

Comment: Thanks @Chiel.I don't know why people downvote when a beginner asks questions.StackOverflow community is not at all helpful.Quora is much better than this.

Comment: Here on stack overflow you are likely to get downvotes if the question does not conform to the rather strict rules of the site. It does not mean that people do not want to help or that your question is not relevant.

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong in the question??.I have  explained my problem and wanted some help @Chiel

Comment: My guess is that the downvoter found this question too vague. Reading this through may help in getting an idea what kind of questions are good: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: You already asked this question - it was put on hold, and then you deleted it.  If it was closed once as a low quality question, simply asking the exact same question again will most likely just cause it to get closed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what type of technology your server or the client use if they can communicate with each other using some sort of standard "protocol".

There are many ways to communicate both sides (client and server) like sockets, xml, json, etc. They just need to understand each other.

In your particular case I suggest to build a REST or RESTful API (https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.3/) on the server and a REST client library on the client.

There are many ways and libraries to call REST APIs from C#:

The built-in method would be using HttpWebRequest as you can see on this [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/call_a_rest_web_service/):

```
private async Task<JsonValue> FetchWeatherAsync (string url)
{
    // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create (new Uri (url));
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";

    // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
    using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync ())
    {
        // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream ())
        {
            // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
            JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run (() => JsonObject.Load (stream));
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString ());

            // Return the JSON document:
            return jsonDoc;
        }
    }
}
```

But I don´t recommend it if you don´t want your app to be full of crap (boiler plate code) everywhere.

A helper library could be, for example, [RESTSharp](http://restsharp.org/). It allows you to build REST calls easily and cast the response to your typed objects. Here´s and example:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
// client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); // replaces matching token in request.Resource

// easily add HTTP Headers
request.AddHeader("header", "value");

// add files to upload (works with compatible verbs)
request.AddFile(path);

// execute the request
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

// or automatically deserialize result
// return content type is sniffed but can be explicitly set via RestClient.AddHandler();
RestResponse<Person> response2 = client.Execute<Person>(request);
var name = response2.Data.Name;

// easy async support
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
});

// async with deserialization
var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<Person>(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Data.Name);
});

// abort the request on demand
asyncHandle.Abort();
```

You can search "C# REST client" on google and judge by yourself. But IMHO, the easier and nicer to code REST client I´ve ever used is [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit). 
Why? you define API calls and responses with just an interface. No coding required at all! Even more, all your API calls will be async by default, something needed for mobile apps to be responsive. From the author´s readme:

```
public interface IGitHubApi
{
    [Get("/users/{user}")]
    Task<User> GetUser(string user);
}

var gitHubApi = RestService.For<IGitHubApi>("https://api.github.com");
var octocat = await gitHubApi.GetUser("octocat");
```

I´ve used this library on Xamarin Android/iOS projects and it works well. No issues at all.

Hope it helps

Comment: I didn't knew about this and NoBody was helping.Now I am fully capable to build.Thanks a million times :) @xelon

Comment: Hi Rajendra, no problem. You may want to mark my answer as correct